# Spring MVC 404 erro http request

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to java Spring framework i am creating simple redirecting application.but i am getting http 404 error
the code is as follows

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:flow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
       xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
       xmlns:osgi="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-2.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-4.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-4.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi-1.2.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.0.xsd">
         <context:component-scan base-package="com.webservlet"/>
</beans>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!-- was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd" >


        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>
        <bean class="com.webservlet.LoginServlet">

        </bean>

    <!--
    Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
    for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
    define an explicit mapping for it.
    -->
    <bean id="indexMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="homeMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="home.htm">homeController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="loginMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="login.htm">loginController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
     <bean id="about_usMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="about_us.htm">about_usController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
     <bean id="contact_usMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props> <prop key="contact_us.htm">contact_usController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <!--
    The index controller.
    -->

    <bean name="indexController"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
          p:viewName="index" />
    <bean name="homeController"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
          p:viewName="home" />
    <bean name="loginController"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
          p:viewName="login" />


    <bean name="about_usController"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
          p:viewName="about_us" />
    <bean name="contact_usController"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
          p:viewName="contact_us" />
    <!--
        The viewResolver
    -->
    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />

</beans>
```

The `LoginServlet`.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package com.webservlet;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController;

/**
 *
 * @author sharathsind
 */
@Controller
@EnableWebMvc


public class LoginServlet {



    @RequestMapping(value="/login.do",method = RequestMethod.POST)

public ModelAndView handleRequestInternal()  {

       return new ModelAndView("home");
    }

}
```

login.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Login Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
          <script>
            function display(string) {
            document.getElementById("form").action = string;
            }
        </script>
        <form  method="post" id="form" onsubmit="display('login.do')">
            UserName: <input type="text" name="userName"><br>
            PassWord: <input type="password" name="passWord">
            <input type="submit" value="submit"/>

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

when i redirect to login.do it is not showing.can anyone help me
thanks in advance

Comment: You have tried both `xml configuration` and annotation for the same controllers .. so the dispatcher can't handle it . instead try with either of the one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your configuration is flawed not to mention that it configures to much. For starters remove `@EnableWebMvc` from your `LoginServlet` as it isn't doing anything. It should be placed on a `@Configuration` based class and used in a Java Config based application you are using XML.

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

       xsi:schemaLocation="
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

         <context:component-scan base-package="com.webservlet">
            <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
         </context:component-scan>
</beans>
```

Should scan for everything but controllers (notice the `exclude-filter`).

dispatcherServlet.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

         <context:component-scan base-package="com.webservlet" use-default-filters="false">
            <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
         </context:component-scan>

          <mvc:annotation-driven />

          <mvc:view-controller path="/index.html" view-name="index" />
          <mvc:view-controller path="/home.html" view-name="home" />
          <mvc:view-controller path="/login.html" view-name="login />
          <mvc:view-controller path="/about_us.html" view-name="about_us" />
          <mvc:view-controller path="/contact_us.html" view-name="contact_us" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />

</beans>
```

Scan only for controllers, notice the `include-filter` and `use-default-filters="false"` attribute. Enable `@RequestMapping` parsing with `<mvc:annotation-driven />` and for those pesky view controllers use `<mvc:view-controller />`.

For more information on the `mvc` namespace I suggest a read of [this section](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config) of the reference guide.

Another tip use versionless xsd files instead of the versioned one, this will take care of using the latest version of the xsd available on the classpath.

Comment: it works, thanks, we are using netbean, but the code generate by it is not good at all. Thank you