# Request resource not found status 404

Tags: java, xml, spring

```
package com.test.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.test.dao.UserDAOImpl;
import com.test.model.User;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/service/user/")
public class SpringRestController {

    UserDAOImpl userDAOImpl=new UserDAOImpl();

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=application/json")   
    public User getUser(@PathVariable int id) {
      User user=userDAOImpl.getUserById(id);
      return user;
     }

     @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=application/json")
     public List<User> getAllUsers() {
      List<User> users=userDAOImpl.getAllUsers();
      return users;
     }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>sample</display-name>
  <servlet><servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

url

```
localhost:8080/sample/service/user/
```

I am getting this error please help me to resolve this error.I am using spring json rest. This error mostly comes at the time of giving request.

Comment: so whats your error?

Comment: How do you make the request?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring MVC 404 erro http request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24603981/spring-mvc-404-erro-http-request)